# Multiple debezium connector for one Mysql DB

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to create multiple connector same datebase, but getting exception

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: A slave with the same server_uuid/server_id as this slave has connected to the master; the first event 'mysql-bin.000004' at 1088, the last event read from './mysql-bin.000004' at 1310, the last byte read from './mysql-bin.000004' at 1310. Error code: 1236; SQLSTATE: HY000.\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:230)

Answer (score 5):

In each connector configuration, the field 'database.server.id' must be unique.

Delete each connector (except one) and recreate it with a new 'database.server.id'.

Comment: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html Table 16 `server-id` parameter: 

"The value for the server-id must be unique for each server and replication client in the MySQL cluster. During MySQL connector set up, Debezium assigns a unique server ID to the connector.".

Comment: .with("database.server.id", LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC))
It works like a charm.